# Differential forms and simplification

Tags: differential-forms

Let us suppose we have

$$(\partial_x \alpha - \partial_x \bar{\alpha} )(df+\lambda)\wedge dx+ (\partial_y \alpha - \partial_y \bar{\alpha} )(df+\lambda) \wedge dy + (\partial_z \alpha - \partial_z \bar{\alpha})(df+\lambda)\wedge dz$$

and then we decided to write those as

$$\partial_x (\alpha - \bar{\alpha} )(df+\lambda)\wedge dx+ \partial_y (\alpha - \bar{\alpha} )(df+\lambda) \wedge dy+\partial_z (\alpha -  \bar{\alpha} )(df+\lambda)\wedge dz$$

where $\alpha$ is a complex function, $df$ is a one-form and so is $\lambda$.

Can we write this summation as $d[(\alpha -\bar{\alpha})(df+\lambda)]$?

Answer (score 1):

It's the negative of your answer. To get $d\alpha\wedge \lambda$, for example, you need to switch the order in $d\lambda\wedge dx$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

By the Leibniz rule,

\begin{align*}
&\ d[(\alpha - \overline{\alpha})(df + \lambda)]\\ 
=&\ d(\alpha - \overline{\alpha})\wedge(df + \lambda) + (\alpha - \overline{\alpha})d(df + \lambda)\\
=&\ (\partial_x(\alpha - \overline{\alpha})dx + \partial_y(\alpha - \overline{\alpha})dy + \partial_z(\alpha - \overline{\alpha})dz)\wedge(df + \lambda) + (\alpha - \overline{\alpha})(d(df) + d\lambda)\\
=&\ \partial_x(\alpha - \overline{\alpha})dx\wedge(df + \lambda) + \partial_y(\alpha - \overline{\alpha})dy\wedge(df + \lambda) + \partial_z(\alpha - \overline{\alpha})dz\wedge(df + \lambda) + (\alpha - \overline{\alpha})d\lambda\\
=&\ (\alpha - \overline{\alpha})d\lambda-\partial_x(\alpha - \overline{\alpha})(df + \lambda)\wedge dx - \partial_y(\alpha - \overline{\alpha})(df + \lambda)\wedge dy - \partial_z(\alpha - \overline{\alpha})(df + \lambda)\wedge dz.
\end{align*}

So your expression can be written as $(\alpha - \overline{\alpha})d\lambda - d[(\alpha-\overline{\alpha})(df + \lambda)]$. If $d\lambda = 0$ (i.e. $\lambda$ is closed), then your expression can be written as $-d[(\alpha - \overline{\alpha})(df + \lambda)]$.

Comment: But isn't it like we are considering that the partial derivative wrt x for example is for both $(\alpha - \bar{\alpha})$ and $(df+\lambda)$ both multiplied by each other? Like after your 4th "=" you have $\partial_x(\alpha - \bar{\alpha})(df+\lambda)$ but this $\partial_x$ is only for the first term $(\alpha-\bar{\alpha})$ and not for both,i.e, $\partial_x(\alpha - \bar{\alpha})(df+\lambda)$. So is it appropriate to consider that they will be written in a compact form as an exterior derivative for BOTH as $d[(\alpha - \bar{\alpha})(df+\lambda)]$ ?

Comment: Also can you please explain your next step? Why in the first term there is a wedge and no wedge in the second term?

Comment: I don't understand what your objection is. When I write $\partial_x(\alpha - \overline{\alpha})dx\wedge(df + \lambda)$ I mean the following: take the partial derivative of the function $\alpha - \overline{\alpha}$ with respect to $x$ and multiply it by the form $dx\wedge(df + \lambda)$. As for your second comment, there is still a wedge in the first term after the fourth $=$ sign. I have just used the fact that if you reverse the order of a wedge product of two one-forms, you introduce a minus sign, i.e. I used the fact that $dx\wedge (df + \lambda) = -(df + \lambda)\wedge dx$.

Comment: This is not what I meant, we know that in general $\partial_xfdx+\partial_ydy+\partial_zdz$=$df$. But here in the question, f in the first step is $(\alpha-\bar{\alpha})(df+\lambda)$ but it is not the case because $\partial_x$ acts only on $(\alpha-\bar{\alpha})$ so this is our f. In other words shouldn't this be equal to $d[(\alpha-\bar{\alpha})](df+\lambda)$? Watch the bracket.

Comment: If you're asking whether $d[(\alpha - \overline{\alpha})(df + \lambda)] = d[(\alpha - \overline{\alpha})](df + \lambda)$, the answer is no. If you're asking whether your initial expression is equal to $d[(\alpha - \overline{\alpha})](df + \lambda)$, the answer is no. Please let me know if either of these two things are relevant to the question you are trying to ask me.

Comment: Yes, the second thing you wrote. Thank you for rephrasing it.

Comment: So first of all, as $d[(\alpha - \overline{\alpha})]$ and $(df + \lambda)$ are one-forms, you should write $d[(\alpha - \overline{\alpha})]\wedge(df + \lambda)$ not $d[(\alpha - \overline{\alpha})](df + \lambda)$. The reason why your initial expression is not equal to $d[(\alpha - \overline{\alpha})]\wedge(df + \lambda)$ is that the first term in the latter is $\partial_x(\alpha - \overline{\alpha})dx\wedge(df + \lambda)$, whereas the first term in the former is $\partial_x(\alpha - \overline{\alpha})(df + \lambda)\wedge dx$; these are negatives of one another.

Comment: thank you michael, just concerning your second line in your answer, can I write the second term as $(\alpha-\bar{\alpha}))\wedge d(df+\lambda)$. Is it the same thing as with no wedge?

Comment: Yes it is. Wedging a function with a form is the same as multiplying the form by the function.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answers.